# Linux supporting JSP

Tags: linux, jsp

Does every Linux server support JSP files?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to run JSPs (Java Server Pages) you need to have a Java servlet container or Java EE application server running on the server. That's not something that's installed and running by default on any Linux server; the administrator has to have set it up.

A commonly used servlet container is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a JSP (servlet) container *available* for every Linux distribution I've ever heard of, yes; most distros I've installed have not installed one by default, but have made one or more available in their package repositories so installing one is easy (e.g., `apt-get install tomcat5.5` or similar).

People typically use [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), or [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/), or [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/), etc. There's quite a list of application servers on the [Wikipedia page for J2EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J2ee).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.
Slightly longer answer: definitely not out of the box (not every server), but adding support should be possible in most if not all cases.
Caveat: if by linux server you mean some virtual hosting plan, then probably no, unless specified otherwise.